# IE7/IE8 and frozen animated gifs

Tags: internet-explorer, animated-gif

I'm quite sure this is an old problem.

This is how i render my animated gif:

```
 <img id='loading' alt='loading' style="display: none; position:  
    relative; left:10px; top:2px;" src="<%= Url.Image("loading.gif") %>" />
```

This is how I'm desperately trying to show it at the moment:

```
showLoading: function(gifId, butId) {
        var n = gifId != undefined ? gifId : 'loading';
        var l = $('#' + n);

        //if browser is stupid
        if ('v' == '\v') {
            var s = l.attr('src');
            var x = document.getElementById(n);
            x.style.visibility = "visible";
            x.style.display = "inline";
            setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + n + "').src = '"+s+"';",  
                        100);
        } else {
            l.show();
        }
        if (butId != undefined)
            $('#' + butId).css('cursor', 'default').attr("disabled", true);
    },
```

**Problem:**
Animated gif appears frozen, there is no animation

Strangest thing is that on other page everything works like a charm.

P.s. it's painful not to rant about IE... argh...

**EDIT:**

Wrapped around with span:

```
  <span id='loading' style='display: none;
                position: relative; left: 0px; top: 2px;'>
                <img alt='loading' src="<%= Url.Image("loading.gif") %>" />
            </span>
```

changed js to:

```
 if ('v' == '\v') {
            var f = function() {
                l.show();
                l.attr('src', l.attr('src'));
            };
            setTimeout(f, 100);
        } else {
            l.show();
        }
```

and mystically - it works now.

Comment: you can rant about IE, no one will be mad. I had the same bug... usually IE doesn't really like the .src. If I were you'd I'd do it using something else

Comment: Reseting src is a hack that should solve this issue (http://www.ryantetek.com/2009/06/animated-progress-loading-bar-upon-form-submit-javascript/). Somehow it does not.

Comment: And no... I should not rant about it. Got too much material. Will get banned for sure. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this once. If I tried to use JavaScript to show a little loading throbber as the browser moved to a page that was going to take a while to load, IE wouldn't animate the GIF. I solved it by putting the loading throbber directly into the HTML (not inserted via JavaScript) in a hidden div:

```
<div id="pseudo-progress-area" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Please wait while we process your PayPal transaction...</h3>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="/Media/Template/Images/LoadingProgressBar.gif" alt="" />
    </p>
</div>
```

and then using JavaScript to toggle the visibility of the div after a short delay (this is using an older version of the Prototype library, but you get the idea):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    // We have to call this function via a setTimeout() or else IE7 won't
    // animate the GIF as the next page is loading.
    var fnHideConfirmation = function() {
        Element.hide( 'confirmation-area' );
        Element.show( 'pseudo-progress-area' );
    };    
</script>
```

That function is triggered in the form's submit button:

```
<input 
    type="submit"
    class="button"
    name="SubmitConfirmation"
    value="Buy Now →"
    onclick="setTimeout(fnHideConfirmation, 50);" />
```

So instead of delaying the src attribute change, leave it alone and just delay the call to your entire showLoading() function. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Somehow worked. I even don't want to know what exactly fixed it. :D

Comment: Ha! I would tell you, but I don't remember WHY it fixes it, just that it fixes it. =)

Comment: @NicholasPiasecki this doesn't works for me can you help me? :(

Answer (score 5):

[Spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/) works for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I found accepted answer a bit complex to understand or implement however I had the same issue while doing this,

I had following HTML

```
<div id="progress_wheel_div" align="center" style="height:100%; display:none; vertical-align: middle;">
    <img src="images/progress_wheel.gif" style="margin-top: 204px;"/>
    <p class='arbitText' style="font-weight: bold;">Processing, Please wait!</p>
</div>
```

and in java script I was doing this

```
function onSubmit() {

   var divProgressWheel = document.getElementById("progress_wheel_div");
   divProgressWheel.style.display = "block";
}
```

But it was not animating gif file,

**Solutions**

Updated my java script and made it like following

```
function onSubmit() {    
   setTimeout(showProgress, 500);
}

function showProgress() {

    var divProgressWheel = document.getElementById("progress_wheel_div");

    divProgressWheel.innerHTML = "<img src='images/progress_wheel.gif' style='margin-top: 204px;'/><p class='arbitText' style='font-weight: bold;'>Processing, Please wait!</p>";
    divProgressWheel.style.display = "block";
}
```

please notice that divProgressWheel.innerHTML is same as what I had in html.
There fore we can remove unnecessary html so modified html would be;

```
<div id="progress_wheel_div" align="center" style="height:100%; display:none; vertical-align: middle;">

    </div>
```