# animated gif is not animating

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I have an animated gif in the master page which will load
 whenever user clicks certain buttons.
The gif displays but doesn't animate in IE. I have added the class of hide(ZURB) to div and show and hide the div based on this class(*addClass/removeClass* Jquery).

**NOTE:** The gif animates, if I use *hide()* and *show()* methods in Jquery and remove the zurb css class *'.hide'* that I have added.

I want to set the visibility of the div to hidden in the master page and then toggle it in only few child pages. How can I achieve this?

CSS:

```
#loading{position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#666;background-image:url('ajax-loader.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;z-index:10000000;  opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
```

HTML Master Page:

```
  <div id="loading" runat="server" class="hide"></div>
```

Jquery in child page:

```
 $("#<%=Master.FindControl("loading").ClientID %>").removeClass("hide");
```

CSS of hide (Zurb):

```
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-render img  onclick. Try something like that

```
function showProgress() {
        var pb = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        pb.innerHTML = '<img src="./progress-bar.gif" width="200" height ="40"/>';
        pb.style.display = '';
    }

and in your html:

<input type="button" value="button" onclick="showProgress()" />
<div id="progressBar" style="display: none;">
    <img src="./progress-bar.gif" width="200" height ="40"/>
</div>
```

See similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known IE limitation. you can load  and set display:none; Then you can set visibility true when user click certain button.
Two helpful link:
[Animated GIF in IE stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping) And 
[IE7/IE8 and frozen animated gifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803610/ie7-ie8-and-frozen-animated-gifs)